# Replace \x00\x00\x00 to empty in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe, there is one column, some rows contain '\x00\x00\x00'. I'd like to replace to empty.
My code is like this:

```
df.loc[df['column1']=='\x00\x00\x00','column1'] = ''
```

After that, when print this column, it's still same, no changes.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you have a cell with three NUL characters? Where did the data come from?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The data is from a txt file. I encode it to 'unicode_escape' and decode it to utf-8, then some row contains '\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: What you did mangled the text. This page is Unicode. There's no reason to "decode" a UTF8 file. Python strings are Unicode already, they don't need any escaping. What you did either returned the original text or mangled it.

Comment: Were you trying to load a CSV file that started with a Byte-Order-Mark perhaps? Post the code you used to load the file and a sample of the data. That's where the problem is. If you use `read_csv` you can pass the encoding to use to read the data. You can use `utf_8_sig` to load a UTF8 file with a BOM. You can use `utf_8` if for any reason a different encoding was used by default. You can use one of the other [encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) if the file uses a single-byte codepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work ?

```
df['column1']=df['column1'].str.replace('\x00\x00\x00','')
```